# Text Classification Implementation

Tags: .net, xml, visual-c++

I've been trying to implement a text classification system. It needs to read a text file, and extract the words and the word frequency. So far, I've been planning to parse the words, put them in a dictionary and save it to an XML file. I am using C++/CLI.

Is this a good implementation or is there a simpler or better implementation?

May be related question (some code implementation): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631309/save-dictionary-to-xml-file

Comment: My immediate reaction is that the general idea isn't very useful -- regenerating the data from the text is probably about as easy as parsing XML correctly. Other than that, I'm a bit uncertain why you'd mess with C++/CLI for it. If you want C++, using C++. If you want .NET, use C#. C++/CLI is one of those "neither fish nor fowl" things, that's better avoided unless truly required.

Comment: Yeah, I am pretty much a very beginner users. About C++/CLI, I've only heard about it in halfway. But more on the question, don't I need the dictionary to make sure the words are not recorded twice?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there may be better solutions but given your "beginner" status what is the target of better; you can optimize for speed, or for portability.

A binary data structure that could be randomly accessed would be faster, as XML is but a data exchange format; this of course makes it great for portability.

You will need a binary data structure anyway, while you are parsing out the words, until you are ready the write out the XML.